# How can you show this relation between primes and roots of unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers

If $p$ is a prime number, how can you show that there are exactly $p^{n-1}(p-1)$ primitive $p^n$-th roots of unity?

I am a little stuck on how to begin this proof. Do you need to use orders or consider roots of unity in polar terms? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\varphi(p^n)=(p-1)p^{n-1}$. Since $$\zeta_k=\exp\frac{2\pi k}{p^n}$$ is an $p^n$-th root of unity iff $(k,p^n)=1$, you get your result.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what the group contains. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @RXY15 I initially misread your question.

Comment: @RXY15 Euler's totient.

Comment: Hmm I haven't learned that yet but I will look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are $p^n$ $p^n$th roots of unity. The ones that aren't primitive are the ones that are also $p^{n-1}$th roots of unity, and there are $p^{n-1}$ of them. So, the number of primitive ones in $p^n-p^{n-1}$.